# How do I integrate this rational function of quintics?

Tags: calculus

I'm asked to integrate $\int\frac{4x^5-1}{(x^5+x+1)^2}dx$
I just found out that in general, quintics cannot be factored using finitely many basic arithmetic operations. So is this a "fair" question? It seems that I will not be able to do this question without the help of a computer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how obvious this would be without seeing Ross's solution from Alpha, but dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^2$ yields

$$\int\frac{4x^3-\frac1{x^2}}{(x^4+1+\frac1x)^2}dx$$

which reduces to $\int u^{-2}du$ after the substitution $u=x^4+1+\frac1x.$

Comment: @Mark:  seeing the coefficient $4$ could prompt one to look for an $x^4$ to differentiate.  That one wasn't me.  Mike:  well done.

Comment: How did you deduce that denominator?

Comment: @Mark If you're asking how I got the denominator, $\frac{(x^5+x+1)^2}{x^2}=(\frac{x^5+x+1}{x})^2$.  If you're asking how I figured to divide top and bottom by $x^2$, that's tougher to answer.  After seeing Ross's answer, I suspected there had to be some sort of trick.  Took a couple minutes to see it.

Comment: @Mike: That's pretty amazing! But what exactly made you suspicious that there was a trick? I wouldn't think to divide by $x^2$ in a million years, even after seeing Ross' answer.

Answer (score 1):

I fed it to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20%284x%5E5-1%29/%28x%5E5%2bx%2b1%29%5E2), which reports the integral is $-\frac x{x^5+x+1}+C$.  I haven't checked it and step-by-step was not available.  But it does say that $x^5+x+1$ factors as $(x^2+x+1)(x^3-x^2+1)$.  Whether it is fair to expect you to find that, I leave to you.